# Setting up a new store in a subdirectory in Magento 1.8

Tags: php, magento, subdirectory

I have used [this guide](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/) in a previous installation with Magento 1.7 and it worked well, but I am using version 1.8 now and it doesn't seem to work at all.

The edits I made the following edits to the index.php:

```
$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../includes/config.php';

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../app/Mage.php';
```

to properly find the appropriate files.

And I added this to the end (with lic23rdst being the website name):

```
$mageRunCode = 'lic23rdst'; 

$mageRunType = 'website'; 

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

When I try to access the new store I get this message:

> app/Mage.php was not found

Can anyone assist me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just symlink the directory?

```
ln -s otherstore .
```

Now store.com and store.com/otherstore will point to the same filesystem.

You can use some logic in your `index.php` to determine what the store code should be.

You also have the option to include store codes in the URL, then Magento will take care of the logic and filesystem for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have enabled this but I seem unable to access the category the way I did originally http://tostny.com/index.php/breakfast.html, it gives me a 404 error. Also accessing the new store view http://tostny.com/lic23rdst/ doesn't seem to work. I have removed the folder with the index.php and .htaccess file. Are there any steps I am missing?

Comment: In your symlink I think you have to change args: `ln -s otherstore .` => `ln -s . otherstore`